# Random direction of sorting in a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql

Is is possible to randomly chose whether to sort ascending or descending on a PostgreSQL query?

Comment: You could simulate this using a randomly generated number, if 0 sort with ascending, if 1 sort with descending

Answer (score 0):

with some effort you can, eg:

```
with r as (select random() r)
, c as (select r,d.oid,datname,row_number() over(order by d.oid) a, row_number() over(order by d.oid desc) d from pg_database d join r on true)
select oid,datname from c order by case when r > 0.5 then a else d end;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vAKkALzBbNwfxDa5ZcjPoM/1

here I sort by oid with random order.

if `random()` is not principal, but you rather want not mathematical random, you can skip join and `random()` call with smth like:

```
t=# with c as (select oid,datname,row_number() over(order by d.oid) a, row_number() over(order by d.oid desc) d from pg_database d )
select oid,datname from c order by case when ('0.'||split_part(localtimestamp::text,'.',2))::float > 0.5 then a else d end;
  oid   |                        datname
--------+-------------------------------------------------------
 217408 | sandbox
 217407 | a
 217406 | x
 201096 | db
```